# How do I generate .po Files in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

I am using Win and CakePHP 3.1. I read the docs and used `bin\cake i18n extract` to generate a default.po file.

The problem is that it is not finding/using the __ function uses I made in a xxx.ctp File (for example ). When I create those by hand (msgid, msgstr...), it works like a charm, but I would like to use the extract. Because it's convenient and you´re not missing any translations. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.

It ask´s you "What is the path you would like to extract?" I thought it meant the path I like to extract the file to...

After choosing ./cakephp/src it did what I wanted.

Solved!